# Mailkit LOGIN Failed

Tags: c#, exception, outlook, imap, mailkit

I'm developing an application that is supposed to move and distribute incoming mails for our clients.

The current version runs without OAuth2 so I was tasked with developing a completely new version that works with OAuth2 in C#.

I'm totally new to C# (been working with it professionally for about 1.5 months now) and have no idea about the mechanics of Outlook, Exchange and all that, so I'm basically learning everything on the go.

So much for the intro- I've been working with Mailkit and judging by what I found out about my problem, I do get an Access Token successfully.

But when I try to connect, the method below just throws `MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException: "LOGIN failed."`

The following is the method that is supposed to fetch all mails in a mailbox (I'm mostly playing around with this at the moment to learn all the methods and mechanics of Mailkit before actually starting to work on the final application, and fetching all mails seemed to be a simple enough example to get everything working around it)

As a heads-up; my company uses Exchange Online, if that makes any difference in what I need to do

```
static async Task<List<string>> GetEmails(string accessToken)
        {
            var emails = new List<string>();

            using (var client = new ImapClient())
            {
                await client.ConnectAsync("outlook.office365.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
                await client.AuthenticateAsync("[my mail address]", accessToken);

                MessageBox.Show("Test");

                //var inbox = client.Inbox;
                //inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
                //var uids = inbox.Search(SearchQuery.All);

                //foreach (var uid in uids)
                //{
                //    var message = inbox.GetMessage(uid);
                //    emails.Add(message.TextBody);
                //}

                await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
            }

            return emails;
        }
```

If someone can exactly tell me what's wrong, that'd be great, but from what I've researched, it can be a number of problems and "LOGIN failed" is not necessarily the most informative of exceptions. So I'd already be happy for some hints or a list of suggestions on what to try or work out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your OAuth2.0 permissions, etc are setup correctly on the server, then the problem is the following line of code:

```
await client.AuthenticateAsync("[my mail address]", accessToken);
```

The generic `AuthenticateAsync(string username, string password)` method that you are using above does not attempt OAUTH2.0 - it will only attempt the password-based authentication mechanisms (such as "LOGIN" in your case).

Instead, what you need to use is:

```
var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2("[my mail address]", accessToken);
await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);
```

This `AuthenticateAsync(SaslMechanism)` method will now properly use the XOAUTH2 SASL mechanism to authenticate using the provided auth token and should work (assuming the token is valid, of course).

Comment: Judging by the fact that I know receive `MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException: "Authentication failed."` I assume something with the OAuth2 setup on the serverside is wrong?

Comment: Either that or you used the wrong scope(s) (which is extremely common). I recommend reading my guide: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/ExchangeOAuth2.md